# rsync delete/don't delete depending on directory

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, raspbian

I rsync using

```
rsync --archive --delete --verbose ${target} user@remote:/some/path/${target}
```

note the `--delete` option

I start from `$HOME` in ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

- when I call with target=`Sources` (a directory with my code & dev), rsync copy files on remote and delete on remote files no longer present on local.
- when I call with target=`Documents` or `Bureau` (one of skeleton dir created with the account), files are copied, but deleted files on local are not deleted on remote.

What do I miss ?

---

- sources host ubuntu 20.04.6
- remote host raspbian 10
- rsync version 3.1.3 protocol 31
- `/some/path` on remote is not a home dir.